# Extracting the first mention from retweets in a python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My df looks like this:

```
record = { 
 'text_con_RT_t' : ['RT @Blanc_: ramdon text #hashtag quiere ', '@GonM ramdon text', 'RT @IvEc: @GonzM ramdon text', 'hOLA ramdon text ' ], 
 'rt' : ['RT', '' , 'RT','' ]
}
    
# create a dataframe 
dataframe2 = pd.DataFrame(record,
                         columns = ['text_con_RT_t', 'rt'])
```

I would like to get something like this:

| text_con_RT_t | rt | usr_rt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| RT @Blanc_: ramdon text #hashtag quiere | RT | blanc |
| @GonM ramdon text |  |  |
| RT @IvEc: @GonzM ramdon text | RT | ivec |
| hOLA ramdon text |  |  |

But i havent succeded, in cases where there is starts with mention, but not retweet, my results looks like this:

| text_con_RT_t | rt | usr_rt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| RT @Blanc_: ramdon text #hashtag quiere | RT | blanc |
| @GonM ramdon text |  | gonm ramdon text |
| RT @IvEc: @GonzM ramdon text | RT | ivec |
| hOLA ramdon text |  | NaN |

I have tried with this:

```
try:
   dataframe2["usr_rt"] = dataframe2.text_con_RT_t.str.lower().str.split(':').str[0].str.split('@').str[1]
except dataframe2["rt"]==None: # complicated failed
   dataframe2["usr_rt"] = ""
```

Also with this

```
if dataframe2["rt"] == "RT":
  return (dataframe2["usr_rt"] == dataframe2.text_con_RT_t.str.split(':').str[0].str.split('@').str[1])
```

What am I missing? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy.where` to conditionally keep values from extracted value:

```
dataframe2['usr_rt'] = np.where(
  dataframe2.rt == 'RT', 
  dataframe2.text_con_RT_t.str.extract('@(\w+)', expand=False).str.lower(), 
  ''
)

dataframe2
                              text_con_RT_t  rt  usr_rt
0  RT @Blanc_: ramdon text #hashtag quiere   RT  blanc_
1                         @GonM ramdon text            
2              RT @IvEc: @GonzM ramdon text  RT    ivec
3                         hOLA ramdon text
```

Or if retweets always start with `RT`, you can use regex `RT.*?@(\w+)`:

```
dataframe2['usr_rt'] = dataframe2.text_con_RT_t.str.extract('RT.*?@(\w+)', expand=False).str.lower()

dataframe2
                              text_con_RT_t  rt  usr_rt
0  RT @Blanc_: ramdon text #hashtag quiere   RT  blanc_
1                         @GonM ramdon text         NaN
2              RT @IvEc: @GonzM ramdon text  RT    ivec
3                         hOLA ramdon text          NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

I would [personally] find it easier to create values for the new column from `record`. If you added it into `record`, you wouldn't need to change the DataFrame after (which I prefer since I'm not great with `numpy`, so I would just end up extracting the column as list an doing what I've done below anyway).

```py
# allowedChars = '' # '+-.' # add allowed characters
record['usr_rt'] = ['' if not rt == 'RT' else ''.join(
    c for c in txt.split('@', 1)[-1].split(':')[0].lower() 
    if c.isalpha() or c.isdigit() # or c in allowedChars
) for txt, rt in zip(record['text_con_RT_t'], record['rt'])]
```

`if c.isalpha()` allows only characters from the alphabet to remain; remove `or c.isdigit()` if you want to get rid of any numeric character from username as well, and make use of `allowedChars` and *`or c in allowedChars`* if you want to allow some special characters (that includes spaces btw, though I don't think usernames have any).

Anyways, now `pd.DataFrame(record)` would return a DataFrame that looks like

| text_con_RT_t | rt | usr_rt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| RT @Blanc_: ramdon text #hashtag quiere | RT | blanc |
| @GonM ramdon text |  |  |
| RT @IvEc: @GonzM ramdon text | RT | ivec |
| hOLA ramdon text |  |  |